# Understanding Rails: index action- how to return none when no search param present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very basic index action that accepts a search param. And it works...

```
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @reports = Report.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%")
    else
      @reports = Report.all
    end
  end
```

But, it shows ALL records when there is no search parameter...where i'd like it to show none. Tried setting `@reports = nil` but that threw an error.

What's the proper way to do this?

**Update:** adding error message per request:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
Extracted source (around line #16):

13:     <th>File Type</th>
14:     <th>Title</th>
15:   </tr>
16:   <% for report in @reports %>
17:     <tr>
18:       <td><%= report.serial %></td>
19:       <td><%= report.file_kind %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with setting the @reports variable to nil. I suspect that the error is thrown from either an after filter or the view itself, where you probably have some code that doesn't expect @reports to be nil. What error are you getting?

Comment: think i figured it out... replaced `Report.all` with `[]`

Comment: Yes, so the problem is in your view which is expecting @reports to be an array. One quick fix is to set @results to an empty array in your controller if no param is passed, i.e. @results = []

Answer (score 3):

If you want `@reports` to be an array you could do :

```
@reports = params[:search].present?? Report.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").all : []
```

If you want to be uber-clever but not super db efficient this gives you `@reports` as an `ActiveRelation`

```
@reports = Report.where(params[:search].present?? ["title like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"] : "id < 0")
```

But really, the controller isn't the offending portion here. When `@reports` is `nil` where does the error come from? Most likely you should do

```
def index
  @reports = Report.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
end
```

and then make sure the rest of your action can handle a nil `@reports` gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Jesse suggestion is correct. But, it still shows the error on your view page. So, you just add the if condition at the end for end section.

```
... <% end if @reports != nil %>
```